# Material UI OutlinedInput label is invisible

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, react-tsx

We are using [`OutlinedInput`](https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/) from Material UI, but text labels are not rendered. How to fix this?

```
import { Grid, OutlinedInput } from '@material-ui/core';
```

```xml
<Grid container>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <OutlinedInput
      label="invisible label"
      placeholder="HELLO, STACKOVERFLOW!"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => handleValueChange(e.target.value)}
      fullWidth
    />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

instead of expected "invisible label" text, an empty space is rendered (top left corner):

[image: demo screenshot]

Comment: It looks like a problem with styles, can you add overriding styles?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. I don't use any styles

Comment: I've written an answer just now @Mateusz. Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

Like @Daniel L mentioned, you have to use the `InputLabel` component within the `FormControl` component, but in addition to his answer - I had to add a `label` attribute on my `OutlinedInput` component so that the outline on the input would not overlap with my label.

Code without the label attribute:

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '25ch' }} variant="outlined">
    <InputLabel htmlFor='display-name'>Display Name</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
            id="display-name"
            value={displayName}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
            aria-describedby="base-name-helper-text"
            inputProps={{
             'aria-label': 'weight',
            }}
      />
   </FormControl>
```

[image]

Code WITH the label attribute:

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '25ch' }} variant="outlined">
    <InputLabel htmlFor='display-name'>Display Name</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
            id="display-name"
            value={displayName}
            label='Display Name'
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
            aria-describedby="base-name-helper-text"
            inputProps={{
             'aria-label': 'weight',
            }}
      />
   </FormControl>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this component is meant to be used on its own. In the MUI docs, it is primarily used as augmentation for other components such as `TextField`

```
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
```

If you inspect the styles in dev tools, it looks like the CSS property `visibility: hidden` is causing this issue. In fact, if you remove that style, you will see that the label works.

[image]

---

However, if you have already built the majority of your app with this component and you need to show that label, just override it with MUI's styling solutions such as `makeStyles`. In addition, use `notched` prop to allocate space for it

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customInputLabel: {
    "& legend": {
      visibility: "visible"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <OutlinedInput
            classes={{ notchedOutline: classes.customInputLabel }}
            label="visible label"
            placeholder="HELLO, STACKOVERFLOW!"
            fullWidth
            notched
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit musing-morning-sqn5q]

Comment: This doesn't cover the ability for it to show up inside the input box. Is there a way to do that and show the legend when focused or text has been input as normally happens with a textfield label?

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer to this is basically wrapping the component under a `FormControl` and adding an `InputLabel` on top of the `OutlinedInput` component.

Based on your code, it should look like this:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment">Some text</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput
                id="outlined-adornment"
                placeholder="HELLO, STACKOVERFLOW!"
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => handleValueChange(e.target.value)}
                fullWidth
            />
        </FormControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I wrapped OutlinedInput into the FormControl element and attached InputLabe component as a label and that fixed my issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).